# UITextView inside a SwiftUI view background and border color for dark mode (Form)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview, swiftui

I'm trying to get the a UITextView to look the same as a (SwiftUI) TextField, the UITextView code is as follows:

```
...
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TextView>) -> UITextView {
  let textView = UITextView()

  textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body) 
  textView.text = placeholderText
  textView.textColor = .placeholderText
  textView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
  textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.placeholderText.cgColor
  textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
  textView.layer.cornerRadius = 6

  return textView
}
...
```

The full code is similar to [this](https://github.com/SchwiftyUI/MultiLineTextView/blob/master/MultiLineTextView/TextView.swift)

In a Form it looks ok in light mode:
[image]

However, in a Form in dark mode:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with:

```
textView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.placeholderText.cgColor
```

Comment: Could there be something else affecting the color? I'm not getting the same grayish background.

Comment: @CranialDev, the grayish background is from the Form.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out. The `UITextView` that I have is in a `UIViewController` (to control size better)

The grayish background does not appear with that setup.

```
public class CustomTextView: UIViewController {
    var textView: UITextView!

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        self.textView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(textView)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.addSubview(textView)
    }
}
```

Then in your `UIViewRepresentable`

```
public func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<TextViewController_UI>) -> TextViewController_UI.CustomTextView {
    let textViewCont = CustomTextView()

    textViewCont.textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
    textViewCont.textView.text = "placeholder"
    textViewCont.textView.textColor = .placeholderText
    textViewCont.textView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    textViewCont.textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.placeholderText.cgColor
    textViewCont.textView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textViewCont.textView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    return textViewCont
}
```

Comment: .systemBackground is not correct backgroundColor in darkmode